# Zipping and sorting problem

Tags: sorting, scheme

I found this code for zipping in Scheme:

```
(define zip
  (lambda (leftList rightList)
    (if (null? rightList) 
      leftList 
      (if (member (car rightList) leftList) 
        (zip leftList (cdr rightList)) 
        (zip (append leftList (list (car rightList))) (cdr rightList)))))) 

=> (zip '(1 4) '(2 3))
   (1 4 2 3)
```

But I want to sort the result:

```
=> (zip '(1 4) '(2 3))
   (1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: As I know zip produces list a pairs, each pair contianing element of both lists. Here, for example, http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zip_f.html. And if I understanded propertly, your desired result is not zip.

Comment: but there is an error    ;SYNTAX: define: too many forms in value (sort (...))
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.

Comment: ;SYNTAX: define: too many forms in value (sort (...))
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.

Comment: @fahad: Could you explain what you want exactly? You're saying you want to zip and then sort. Except that your `zip` actually looks like `zip`+`flatten` as the result is a flat list. So basically you seem to want a list which contains the items of the two lists in sorted order. That's exactly what leppie gave you, but you rejected that answer. If that's not what you want, you should really put a bit more effort in explaining what you do want as it's completely unclear to me.

Comment: Scheme function, zip that takes two list arguments and returns the list that results from zipping them together, and use it to implement mergesort. You must not try to use global variables, set/setq - you only need the functions discussed in lectures. The function should behave as follows:
    => (zip '(1 2) '(3 4))
    (1 2 3 4)
    => (zip '(1 2) '(2 3))
    (1 2 3)
    => (zip '(1 2) '(1 2))
    (1 2)
    => (zip '(1 3) '(2 4))
    (1 2 3 4)
    => (zip '(1 4) '(2 3))
    (1 2 3 4)

Comment: @erjiang: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @fahad, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: @Roger Pate: I must've missed the memo.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is not called `zip`; it's called `merge`.  Since this is a homework problem, it would be irresponsible to provide the solution.  I can only offer this:

Given two lists *that are already sorted*, what's the easiest way to combine them into a new list that's sorted?  Well, the first thing in each list (the `car` of the list) is the smallest element of its own list, so by comparing them, you can know which one is the smallest of *both* lists.  Then, use recursion to merge what remains.